# How to access JSON encoded data of an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i access this response from server using javascript. 
This is the json encoded data.

```
      [{"cid":"1234","city":"value1","district":"value2","state":"value3"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

This is the ajax code:

```
 function cityauto(ctid){
     var city = document.getElementById(ctid);
     if(city.value.length > 3){
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "city.php",
             data: {term: city.value},
             success: function (data){
                 alert(data);
             }
         });
 }
```

Html code:

```
   <input type="text" name="city" id="cty" onblur="cityauto(this.id);" />
```

onblur i am getting above response from php file in alert box now i need to access that values in javscript.

Comment: Please provide more info about what you wan't to do, what you have tried and your code if any

Comment: I know a guy called *Jason*, maybe he will know... **JSON!!!**

Comment: I dont know how to access it since i am new to json

Comment: Please include information about how you are getting that response from the server, show some code

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming the JSON is returned as a string:

```
var data = '[{"cid":"1234","city":"value1","district":"value2","state":"value3"}]';
// Parse the data as json
var obj = JSON.parse(data)
// Access the ojbect:
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj[0]);     // == Object {cid: "1234", city: "value1", district: "value2", state: "value3"} 
console.log(obj[0].cid); // == 1234
```

The `[0]` is to access the first object inside the JSON, which is an array. Then you just add `.name`, where 'name' is the name of the variable you want. (like `.cid`).

If the JSON is already a object, you can skip the `JSON.parse()`:

```
var obj = [{"cid":"1234","city":"value1","district":"value2","state":"value3"}];
```

And access it like the example above.
(In that case, this question is more about accessing JavaScript objects, instead of JSON)

In your case, you can access the data like this:

```
success: function (data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    // Do stuff with `obj` here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is the only response data then you can access as:

```
var data = [{"cid":"1234","city":"value1","district":"value2","state":"value3"}];
console.log(data[0].cid);

# "1234"
```

### Correction

```
var data = [{"cid":"1234","city":"value1","district":"value2","state":"value3"}];

var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj[0].cid);

# "1234"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  but JSON.parse(data) is required there. before console statement.

Comment: Are you getting string data in success callback of ajax?

Comment: m getting array of data as mentioned above.

Comment: Then you don't need to do JSON.parse(data). JSON.parse is used in case your response is string containing json data as mentioned in 'Cerbrus' solution below.

Comment: Yes it is !  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score -1):

If you recive that response from a page then you can try `$.getJSON` method using jQuery

```
$.getJSON("yourwebsite.com/yourpage", function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
});
```

If you want to use it as a variable, from plain JSON (not accesing to it from another page/request)

`var data = '[{"cid":"1234","city":"value1","district":"value2","state":"value3"}]';`

Then you can use

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
          console.log(key + ":" + val);
  });
```

to access json data in a `foreach` routine...

Or `data[key].innerykey` for example `data[0].cid` `0` is your first array of data, and `.cid` is the key that you want to retrieve, it can be `cid` `city` or whatever you want, if you have more, you can use different number in `data[X]`

Comment: And where might one find the function `$.getJSON`?

Comment: forgot to tell about jquery :P

Comment: I would like to know why the negative votes, my answer is valid, I explained how to use json in two different ways, thank you

Comment: @user1381537 Because nowhere in the question, nor in the code does the author of the question mention jQuery. jQuery is not the solution to everything and in most cases, if someone does not ask for jQuery, don't post it or you'll get downvoted.

Comment: I mentioned to use jQuery but another option to use `var data =` etc but ok whatever