# how to update specific value in json array

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

New to manipulating JSON, I appreciate the help! This project uses VueJs 2 if that makes a difference.

I am trying to update a key value, in this example it is "group" for a specific applicant identified by the ID.

I am trying to accomplish something along of lines of:

```
WHERE applicantID = 3 SET group = 4
```

This is a sample of the JSON I am dealing with:

```
{
    "applicantID" : 3,
    "fullName": "name",
    "value1": 30,
    "value1": 31,
    "value1": 40,
    "value1": 41,
    "value1": "50",
    "value1": "51",
    "group": 0,
    "flag": true,
},
{
    "applicantID" : 4,
    "fullName": "name",
    "value1": 30,
    "value1": 31,
    "value1": 40,
    "value1": 41,
    "value1": "50",
    "value1": "51",
    "group": 0,
    "flag": false,
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access JSON encoded data of an array using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040794/how-to-access-json-encoded-data-of-an-array-using-javascript)

Comment: This looks like it's part of an array. Assuming arr is a defined array, arr[0]["group"] = 4.

Comment: You have duplicate property names (value1) - that won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var item = array.find(x => x.applicantID == 3);
if (item) {
  item.group = 4;
}
```

It will change a value of the group in the original array.

Comment: What if there is more than one item that has ID 3?

Comment: Fantastic! That was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sergii  what if you have to update multiple records then what would be the approach since this will update only one object in the array

Answer (score 1):

if you have to compare multiple fields  you can use this .as an adjustment onto Sergii's answer

```
var item = array.find(x => {
      return x.applicantID == 3 && x.fullName == "name" ;
     });
   if (item) {
     item.group = 4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update a specific value in a JSON array by first getting the specific index then accessing the object property name to edit the value as illustrated below

```
let users = [{name:"John", DOB:"1991", gender:"male"}, {name:"mary", DOB:"1993", gender:"female"}];

//change DOB of Mary
users[1].DOB = "1995";
```

NB You can also loop over the JSON array to update a value at a specific index using the same logic.